# Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy2 v3.0.6 got a exception

Tags: c#, aop, autofac

I use Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy2 to implement my AOP policy.
I updated Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy2 to v3.0.6, i got a exception:

> The component Activator = LookupService (ReflectionActivator),
>   Services = [WordBook.Protocols.Logic.ILookupService], Lifetime =
>   Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership
>   = OwnedByLifetimeScope cannot use interface interception as it provides services that are not publicly visible interfaces. Check your
>   registration of the component to ensure you're not enabling
>   interception and registering it as an internal/private interface type.

This is my sourcecode:

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<ExceptionInterceptor>();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("WordBookLogics")).AsImplementedInterfaces().EnableInterfaceInterceptors();

var container = builder.Build();

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

It works at Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy2 v3.0.5.

Do I need to adjust something when i updated?

Comment: You only upgrade Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy2 nothing else ?  WordBookLogics hasn't changed ?

Comment: No, i don't do anything. I only upgraded Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy2.

Comment: This is related to this [changeset](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy/commit/5ccd16445def5ba7a9268199c035e1cd894e7b39) and this [bug](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy/issues/2). Do you have any non public interface in your assembly ? If so, as stated on the [documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html) you should mark your assembly with `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]`

Comment: By the way, try to avoid Register everything on an assembly. If you need to dynamically register type, use Module and specify each registration. You will have more control on how your registration works.

Comment: If you register LookupService manually instead of AsImplementedInterfaces does it work?

Comment: I register LookupService manually instead of AsImplementedInterfaces, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I public all interface methods in my project. I don't have the problem that intercept internal/private methods.

Comment: No, i still got the exception. I will downgrade to v3.0.5 and continue my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found the problem.

In Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy2 v3.0.5, line 300 of the RegistrationExtensions.cs has IsVisible condition.

But, the IsVisible condition was replaced to Assembly.IsInternalToDynamicProxy() in Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy2 v3.0.6.

The IsVisible property of my public interface is true, but the result that i call Assembly.IsInternalToDynamicProxy() on my public interface is false.

So, my public interface is visible, but it is not mean internal to dynamicproxy.

That's the reason that my interception were not work and got the exception in Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy2 v3.0.6.

I only wait for the owner of Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy2 fixing it.

Comment: The problem was fixed in Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy2 v3.0.7.